# Converting escaped codes in Htop output

Tags: python, bash, shell, htop

I'm attempting to show the hostname above `htop` output, in order to better identify which server its monitoring. I haven't found a good way to do this, but the closest I've gotten is with the command:

```
watch --color -t "hostname; echo q | htop"
```

Unfortunately, due to how `watch` interprets special characters, it renders slightly mangled output like:

[image]

It looks like `watch` is corrupting the newline, tab and carriage return characters. I think I could potentially correct this via a Python or Bash script, but I'm having trouble making sense of the escape syntax. All the special characters seem to be rendered as "(B" followed by 0 to 4 numbers. However, for characters that should be the same, such as what should be new lines after each process row, the escaped character uses a completely different code. For example "(B3263" and "(B3264".

How do I interpret these numbers and convert them back to the correct characters while preserving the color?

Comment: You seem to put a lot of effort into a solution for a problem most terminal applications solve by putting the hostname into the window and / or the tab label.

Comment: @Cerin – You can control delay with `-d --delay=DELAY` and add hostname with `F2 (setup)` then just select `Hostname` from *Available meters*. Is `watch` necessary here?

Comment: @KlausD. Ah, yes, I probably should have mentioned I'm running this inside tmux/tmuxinator, which obscure the window/tab title.

Comment: @TravisClarke, Interesting, that's good to know. I didn't realize that could be selected.